# Image is not aligned vertically in TD

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a table in which each of its TD contains image (more precisely, emoticon) which have same height. Oddly, they are not properly aligned. One emoticon is at the top, the other is at the middle, and the other is at bottom.

Here is a picture to make the explanation easier:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeVpY.png

I tried to copy the HTML structure to jsfiddle, but [it is properly aligned in there](http://jsfiddle.net/uxyjg/). So I believe this is a CSS problem.

However, my try to modify everything results in no avail. I cannot make it aligned properly. I tried `vertical-align:middle` and tried to set the `padding` and `margin` but I cannot make it align properly.

Is there any help to do this?

**EDIT:** it turns out that this CSS is the one that is making the problem:

```
.emotlist {
overflow: auto;
height: 175px;
width: 120px;
}
```

When I remove the `overflow: auto`, it displays as I want it to be. But the problem here: I need the `overflow:auto` to make scrollbar, so in case there are more emoticons added to the table, it will not exceed the defined-height.

**EDIT 2:** I guess it is not the `overflow: auto` which is causing the problem, since it is just working fine in the fiddle (as demonstrated by Sheilender)

**Disclaimer:** I cannot change the HTML structure (in case someone suggest so). I don't have access to the HTML template and what I can do is only style it via CSS.

.

Comment: please add some CSS, so we can check if it's a CSS problem.

Comment: The complete CSS is quite huge, and I'm not sure which one is actually affecting the TD (besides the .emotfill I explained above). However I could provide a link to a site which seem to experience similar problem like me. You could see it here >  http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?act=Post&CODE=02&f=1&t=2352

Comment: I'm assuming the the `TD` elements have the class `.emotlist` applied? And that you're making a single long table with 1 row? Or is it multiple rows? As that'll make a big difference.

Comment: @RemarkLima: No. Please check the fiddle I've provided, it has been answered there with the complete HTML structure. The `.emotlist` is a parent div, and the `valign=middle` also already been used (and I'm also unable to edit the HTML structure since I don't have the access).

Comment: @deathlock Thanks for that - checked the fiddle and I think it's the `&nbsp;` breaking the alignment - not a problem in the fiddle as the broken images caused the cells to be wide enough, if you remove the broken images and set the cells to be narrow then the fiddle will should the same as your image (or thereabouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the `&nbsp;` after each image is being broken to a new line hence the problems.

Try:

```
.emotlist table tr td {
   width: 25px;
}
```

This should make the cell wide enough to accomodate the image and the `&nbsp;`

or

```
.emotlist table tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

To prevent the cell from breaking any lines.

Answer (score 0):

see i have made changes according to your requirement with your css

http://jsfiddle.net/uxyjg/14/

[you can read more about vertical center content](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: It's odd; it seem to be working in the fiddle, but when I tried in my site that still doesn't work. Perhaps there's other CSS that is affecting it. I couldn't provide a link to my CSS, but here's another site which has similar problem like me > http://bleachindonesia.com/forum/index.php?act=Post&CODE=02&f=1&t=2352

Comment: ya it can be because i have tried on fiddle its working fine so might be possible when you implementing the same in code your css its affecting the other css so for find out the exact bug we need the exact css that would be easier for us....

Comment: That is the problem, I think. I don't know which one is affecting it since I have tried removing the ones which I think is the cause, but to no avail. I guess it's between .pformstrip, .tablefill, .emotlist.

Comment: OK, the fiddle is now showing the same - and the forum you've linked to you can see the `&nbsp;` is being broken onto the new line hence causing the misalignment.